# How to set fullscreen video background on Interner Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, video, background

I set fullscreen background video for every browser except the Internet Explorer, you can see it on this link http://sabine.abnahme-server.de/

Is it possible to set full width like on every other browser?

Comment: Do you mean full browser width rather than full screen - full screen is usually not possible programatically - i.e. it needs the user to set it themselves?

Comment: Yes, I meant full width, but we resolved it.
On the video: width 100%, height auto, and on the next segment just added z-index higher than the video element, no overlapp and fullscreen video